# Exchange the x axis for the y axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python code that read several files and returns the next plot:

[image: plot]

Now I want to visualize it exchanging the x axis by the y axis. I know that I can do this in matplotlib just putting `plt.plot(y,x)` instead of `plt.plot(x,y)`, but I have 8 different plots in the figure, so changing everything one by one could be annoying if the number of plots rises: 
Is there a way to change the axis before show the image?

Here is part of the code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))

plt.plot(Ks_d001,std_d001,'k.',ms=2)#,label='all population')
plt.plot(Ks_d002,std_d002,'k.',ms=2)

KS = np.concatenate([Ks_d001,Ks_d002])
STD = np.concatenate([std_d001,std_d002])

grid = np.linspace(11.5,max(KS),50)
k0 = smooth.NonParamRegression(KS, STD, method=npr_methods.SpatialAverage())
k0.fit()       

plt.plot(grid, k0(grid), label="non-param. fit", color='red', linewidth=2)

plt.plot(Ks_Eta_d001,std_Eta_d001,'s',ms=10,color='green',label='Eta d001')
plt.plot(Ks_Eta_d002,std_Eta_d002,'s',ms=10,color='blue',label='Eta d002')

plt.plot(Ks_IP_d001,std_IP_d001,'p',ms=10,color='cyan',label='IP d001')
plt.plot(Ks_IP_d002,std_IP_d002,'p',ms=10,color='orange',label='IP d002')

plt.plot(Ks_GLS_d001,std_GLS_d001,'h',ms=10,color='red',label='GLS d001')
plt.plot(Ks_GLS_d002,std_GLS_d002,'h',ms=10,color='yellow',label='GLS d002')
```

Comment: Do `x, y = y, x` before invoking the plots?

Comment: As I said, in this case I can simply do plt.plot(y,x) or changing the number of row that I read in the file (the same idea of x,y = y,x). I'm trying to find a way to not modify the code, only modify the plot display, if there is one.

Comment: Well, with this you'd have to change the code in just one place, instead of in 8 places. But maybe I did not understand the question. How about posting some more of your code?

Comment: Ok, done! I thought with that would be enough.

Comment: Changing your code in 8 places takes less time than writing (and updating) this question. I don't understand your actual problem.

Comment: I have a solution since the very begining of this question and is not a problem at all, I'm just curious if I can do this because could be useful in the future. And for that I took the time to do the question and edit it.

Comment: I don't think there is a built in method to achieve what you want but you could write a helper function which takes a boolean 'swap' axis arg which does it for you. This way you won't need to swap the axis around for all 8 but just change True to False and vice vera. You could extend this to be a global 'swap all' variable and then just re-run your code for normal and then swapped versions.

Comment: Make a helper function pplot(x,y,0) for plot(x,y) and pplot(x,y,1) for plot(y,x). Then set a variable a to either 0 or 1 and replace your current code with pplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (as far as I know) no function in `matplotlib` but in general you could just use some data-structure to hold your values which makes it easier to change properties globally or individually:

```
#         Name             x            y          m
plots = {'Eta d001': [[Ks_Eta_d001, std_Eta_d001, 's'], {'ms': 10, 'color': 'green'}],
         'Eta d002': [[Ks_Eta_d002, std_Eta_d002, 's'], {'ms': 10, 'color': 'blue'}],
         ...}
```

and then make a plot loop:

```
for plotname, ((x, y, marker), kwargs) in plots.items():
    plt.plot(x, y, marker, label=plotname, **kwargs)
```

changing `x` and `y` is then as easy as:

```
for plotname, ((x, y, marker), kwargs) in plots.items():
    plt.plot(y, x, marker, label=plotname, **kwargs)
```

The dictionary doesn't preserve the original order but when plotting that shouldn't matter much. If it does matter use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of the normal dict.

Comment: I see, is an interesting use of the dictionaries and work well! Thanks for the help!!