# How to rotate a subplot by 90deg in matplotlib without knowing the extent

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a a subplot that I define using `add_subplot()` with gridspec. I am looking to rotate this plot and its contents by 90 degrees, but I don't have the information on the content a-priori. This is because the axis is defined as part of a general Canvas class that I've built. I also do not want to just flip the x and y contents in the function call `ax.plot(y,x)` as this will introduce complications later in my code.

Is there a way to reliably rotate the axes when I create them, so that when I call ax.plot(x,y), the x-data is on the vertical axis, and the y-data on the horizontal axis?

Comment: See [Exchange the x axis for the y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925961/exchange-the-x-axis-for-the-y-axis-in-python)

Comment: Hi, as I said in the question, I would like to transform the plot itself to start with rather than swapping the x and y data in function call.

Comment: Well, you could try to subclass `Axes`, but you are in for a lot of work and limitations. You will be asking yourself why you wouldn't just swap x and y inside a few function calls. You might take a look at [seaborn's source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn) to get an idea how clever use of dictionaries could be the good approach to create plots that optionally are horizontally vs vertically.